# Why JSON.parse removes double quotes?

Tags: javascript, json

Having simple JS code:

```
var str = '[[[0,123,"John Doe"]],[[0,189,"Jane Doe, Mike Smith"]]]';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
document.writeln(obj[1]);
```

[Test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/4UBuT/)

Why double quotes are removed? How can I force JS to not remove double quotes?

---

Or... how can I convert this JSON to array, having each element separated?

For example: `obj[1][2] = "Jane Doe, Mike Smith"`

Comment: The quotes are part of the syntax that defines the content, not the content itself. Why do you want them there?

Comment: quote are here to define it's a string, print will not show it, try typeof on your array elements to check if it's a string

Comment: ...If the quotes are meant to be part of the string content, then you should take care of that in whatever is generating the JSON. Basically your JSON would need to be `"\"Jane Doe, Mike Smith\""`

Comment: I need to get an array of all elements

Comment: @Ωmega You already accomplished that with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @James - I didn't know about `obj[0][0][2]` - yes... I have it already :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want JSON to be printed, convert it back to JSON:

```
document.writeln(JSON.stringify(obj[1]));
```

By using `JSON.parse`, you convert the JSON into a real JavaScript array.  There's no JSON in `obj`, and therefore no quotes.

If you want to manipulate the array, you can do this as you would any other array:

```
var str = '[[[0,123,"John Doe"]],[[0,189,"Jane Doe, Mike Smith"]]]';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
obj[0][0][2] = "John Smith";
```

And then if you want your quotes back, you'll have to convert it back to JSON with `JSON.stringify`.